# Div content slider with arrow image

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have working script that slides content inside div with arrow image up and down.
For some reason cant get fiddle to work but it works on my site just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/w5j2s/

```
function Scroll(id,ud,spd){
    var obj=document.getElementById(id);
    clearTimeout(obj.to);
    if (ud){
        obj.scrollTop=obj.scrollTop+ud;
        obj.to=setTimeout(function(){ Scroll(id,ud,spd); },spd||50)
    }
}
```

I thought I had only one question but now ... First why doesn't fiddle work? Same script, divs, style and it works on my site ... it is not complicated but for some reason i doesn't work on fiddle!

Second now I need div with arrow image but this one I need to slide left to right, not up and down. How do i modify script so i can use the same one for to different divs on same page, one that will scroll up and down and another that will slide left to right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify that the script is in the body:

[image]

For the second part of your question you should write another function similar to `Scroll` that uses `scrollLeft` instead of `scrollTop`

Comment: Well something is wrong. It's all good till width on on #tst is 20px, but when i put it to 200px it dosen't work  http://jsfiddle.net/w5j2s/5/

Comment: you can fix this with a nested div. the child div has a larger width than the parent. see http://jsfiddle.net/w5j2s/6/

Answer (score 0):

Use `Margin-Top` css attribute instead of `scrollTop`:

http://jsfiddle.net/w5j2s/3/

Javascript:

```
var objTimeout;

function scroll(id, ud, spd){
    clearTimeout(objTimeout);
    if (ud){
        var o = document.getElementById('tst');
        var marginInt = parseInt(o.style.marginTop || 0);
        o.style.marginTop = (marginInt + ud) + 'px';
        objTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ scroll(id, ud, spd); }, spd||50);
    }
}
```

Also, there's other corrections to do:

1. Put scrolling `div` inside a wrapper.
2. When calling scroll, be sure that HTML elements will be loaded.